# Beam of plans resolution formula

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I must to determinate equation of the plan that containing the line $r= \begin {cases} x=z+1 \\ y=2z+1\end{cases}$

That passes from O$(0,0,0)$ and parallel to the line $r_1= \begin{cases} x=2z+3\\ y=z+5\end{cases}$

Now I'm going to solve the first. $(ax+by+cz+d)+\lambda(ax+by+cz+d)=0,  x-1+\lambda y-\lambda - (2\lambda +1)z=0$.

Now I'm doing the passage through the origin $(0,0,0)$ and I'm doing the substitution of $x, y, z$ to $0,0,0$. So I have $\lambda =-1$. For finding the parallel  to the r1 I'll going to research the parameters directors and from the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & - 2 \\ 0 & 1 & - 1 \end{bmatrix}$ I've got $l=1, m=1, n=1$. For the formula of the line parallel to the plan I've got $al+bm+cn=0$ and here I'm in stuck. I don't know were I must to do the substitution.

Comment: Does "//" mean "parallel"? Usually it is better to write things in words when you can. Equations are still equations, and the names of variables are always written as math symbols, but if you have a word such as "parallel" that will fit perfectly into a sentence, don't replace it with a symbol.

Comment: @DavidK yeah I mean parallel, now I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have with $p = (x,y,z)^{\dagger}$

$$
r \to p = \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\\0\end{array}\right)+\lambda \left(\begin{array}{c}1\\2\\1\end{array}\right)=p_0+\lambda \vec v_0\\
r_1 \to p = \left(\begin{array}{c}3\\5\\0\end{array}\right)+\lambda_1 \left(\begin{array}{c}2\\1\\1\end{array}\right)=p_1+\lambda_1\vec v_1\\
\Pi\to p\cdot\left(\begin{array}{c}n_x\\n_y\\n_z\end{array}\right)=p\cdot\vec n = 0
$$

now $r\in \Pi\Rightarrow (p_0+\lambda\vec v_0)\cdot \vec n = 0\ \ \forall\ \ \lambda$ giving

$$
\begin{cases}
p_0\cdot\vec n = 0\\
\vec v_0\cdot \vec n = 0
\end{cases}
$$

and finally $r_1\ \  |\ |\ \ \Pi\Rightarrow \vec v_1\cdot \vec n = 0$ hence the sought vector $\vec n$ is found by solving

$$
\begin{cases}
p_0\cdot\vec n = 0\\
\vec v_0\cdot \vec n = 0\\
\vec v_1\cdot \vec n = 0\\
||\vec n|| = 1
\end{cases}
$$

or

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 n_x+n_y& =& 0 \\
 n_x+2 n_y+n_z& = & 0 \\
 2 n_x+n_y+n_z& = & 0 \\
 n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2& =& 1 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

this system of equations does not have solution so I suggest to relax the plane definition from $p\cdot\vec n = 0\ $ to $(p-p^*)\cdot\vec n = 0$

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand how you calculate (1,1,0) and (1,2,0)? Because I have for r=(1, 0,-1) (0,1-2) for the last two d =(-1),(-1) because this are known term $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & - 1 & ¦ - 1 \\ 0 & 1 & - 2 & ¦ - 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Ciao Please. See attached modifications after fixing some typos.